# Links to visited sites are barely visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat, mobile

[image: screenshot of a visited link]

The screenshot says it all. I visited a site, copied the address, posted it in chat (new interface).

The colour used for the link is too close to the background colour, which makes the link barely visible.

Comment: Is this specific to the new mobile chat? if so, I think it needs the mobile-web tag.

Comment: Maybe related: [Visited tags and badges are styled differently to unvisited ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257431/162011).

Comment: The screenshot doesn't actually say it all. To clarify, this is a link in your own message (which gets a special highlight) on [Sci Fi chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) (which has a different color scheme than other chats) on the new mobile web interface. Right? ;-) (Also sometimes useful: your device model and browser version.)

Comment: @JonEricson, well, I mentioned it was a link I visited and posted, but yes, it was on SFF chat. Could you please migrate it to that meta?

Comment: If it's specifically about the new mobile-web view, though... I would think that the developers would prefer it be on Meta.SE? That is what the announcement says. If it's the same issue in both the new mobile web and the regular view of chat, that would be different...

Comment: Look at that I'm famous.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage You're already famous - you're a mod!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that, fixed now. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Verified and fixed. Thank you.